# Lowest eigenvalues of a matrix with divergent entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I asked [this question on computational science stack exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41445/lowest-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-with-divergent-entries), but probably this forum is more appropriate.

In high energy physics we oftentimes encounter the following problem. For a given parametrized matrix $\{H_{ij}(\Lambda)\}$, we know that in the limit $\Lambda\to\infty$ some of its entries become large:

$$
\text{For some $(i,j)$:  }H_{ij}(\Lambda)\to\infty\text{ as }\Lambda\to\infty.
$$

We also know that in the limit $\Lambda\to\infty$ the lowest eigenvalues in the spectrum of $\{H_{ij}(\Lambda)\}$ — which we are most interested in — tend to converge to particular values (while the larger eigenvalues may potentially diverge).

Have we had access to an "infinite-precision" computer, we could just diagonalize the matrix for increasing values of $\Lambda$ extrapolate to $\Lambda\to\infty$. In reality, this is impractical.

I am wondering if there exist any well-known ways to deal with such a situation, at least for some specific cases (such as divergent elements staying on the diagonal and matrix being sparse).

Comment: Is the matrix Hermitian? That makes a big difference.

Comment: Good point, that's surely the most interesting case.

Answer (score 1):

If your family is Hermitian, then you can do an inverse iteration (pick a vector $v,$ and compute the sequence $w_n=A^{-n} v,$ then the bottom eigenvalue is the limit of $\|w_{n-1}\|/\|w_n\|.$ You can compute $A^{-1} w$ quickly using conjugate gradient. The normalized $w_n$ converges to the eigenvector of the bottom eigenvalue, so when you are done, take a random vector orthogonal to the limit unit vector, and repeat.

Comment: Dumb question: isn't invertion computationally as hard as diagonalizaion? Or the point is that we don't invert the whole matrix but rather compute only the inverted matrix applied to a fixed vector?

Comment: @mavzolej correct. The latter is $O(n^2),$ better yet for sparse matrices.